Need to create group based on actions
I have a table and I am only interested in two columns to perform two actions (Ignore or Good),  and based on actions I need to keep only "Good" rows. I have tried several SQL windows functions but not able to achieve what I am looking for.
Here is the data:

There are two actions I need to perform on each row. "cat" or "dog" will be "Good" only when there is value "animal" in the column before on the same date otherwise action will be "Ignore". Similar to this:

Final result should be like this:

Data with all edge cases

Can't be done, there's no before on the same date, unless you have another column to order by.

Please read How to make a good example and Why not upload images of code or data, then improve your question.

So to confirm the logic, because you haven't really explained it: you want Good for all rows where there is animal followed immediately by any number of cat or dog consecutively, so excluding any case of animal followed by another animal, and excluding any case of cat or dog not preceded by animal, all of this partitioned by date?

That's right, Charlieface

Looks like you can just use a conditional windowed COUNT.
SELECT
  CASE WHEN (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE value = 'animal') OVER
          (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', Date) ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) = 0
            AND value <> 'animal')
       OR (value = 'animal' AND LEAD(value) OVER
          (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', Date) ORDER BY Date) <> 'animal')
       THEN 'Good'
       ELSE 'Ignore'
  END AS action
FROM ...

Then simply put that into a subquery and filter on it.
SELECT
  *
FROM (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE value = 'animal') OVER
              (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', Date) ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) = 0
                AND value <> 'animal')
           OR (value = 'animal' AND LEAD(value) OVER
              (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', Date) ORDER BY Date) <> 'animal')
       THEN 'Good'
       ELSE 'Ignore'
    END AS action
    FROM yourTable t
) t
WHERE action = 'good';


This is good and works almost like I need to but there is one issue in here if "animal" repeats in multiple subsequent rows then it flags all rows as "Good". I only need to flag last occurrence of "animal" as good.

How about you show in your question above all possible edge cases. And please don't post images, only paste text (for example you can use Markdown Tables)

I copied excel data in my question above but it got converted to image. This image has all edge cases. It shows data created by date/time and I need to mark with desired outcome "Ignore" or "Good"

One option could be to self join your table data like in the subquery below and use LAG() Over() analytic function as a Case expression's condition to get the "Good" rows.
Self inner join will eliminate the rows with val = 'animal' with no cat or dog or whatever on the same date. Case expression checks if the previous row with the same date has val = 'animal' or not. Outer query is filtered using Where clause and grouped by to get ridd of duplicates.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl (a_date Date, Val Varchar(32));
Insert Into tbl
  Select To_Date('2023-12-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'animal' Union All
  Select To_Date('2023-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'animal' Union All
  Select To_Date('2024-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cat' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dog' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dog' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cat' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cat' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dog' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'animal' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cat' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dog' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dog' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cat' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dog' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'animal' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cat' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cat' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dog' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'animal' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dog' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'animal' Union All 
  Select To_Date('2024-01-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'cat';

--      S Q L : 
SELECT   a_date, val, status
FROM   ( Select Date_Trunc('day', t0.a_date) as a_date, t0.val, 
                Case When t0.val = 'animal' 
                    OR  LAG(t0.val) Over(Partition By Date_Trunc('day', t1.a_date), t1.val 
                                         Order By Date_Trunc('day', t0.a_date)) = 'animal'
                     Then 'Good'
                End as status
        From  tbl t0
        Inner Join tbl t1 ON(Date_Trunc('day', t1.a_date) = Date_Trunc('day', t0.a_date) And 
                             t1.val != 'animal')
      )
WHERE status = 'Good'
GROUP BY   a_date, val
ORDER BY   a_date, val

/*
a_date                  val       status
----------------------  --------  -------
2024-01-03 00:00:00+00  animal    Good
2024-01-03 00:00:00+00  cat       Good
2024-01-03 00:00:00+00  dog       Good
2024-01-06 00:00:00+00  animal    Good
2024-01-06 00:00:00+00  cat       Good
2024-01-08 00:00:00+00  animal    Good
2024-01-08 00:00:00+00  cat       Good
2024-01-08 00:00:00+00  dog       Good      */

See the fiddle here.
Or a version with the timestamps - see the fiddle here:
